# RAM Modules fail when paired

Tags: memory

I have a pair of matched DIMMs installed in a Lenovo M83 desktop.
When tested (using Lenovo diagnostics) with both installed, they fail the test.
However, when tested individually, they pass.
And when I say they are matched, I mean they are the same brand with the same exact specs.
Just looking for some insight as to why this would occur.

Thank you
Greg

Comment: could it be the desktop?

Comment: Are they ECC or non-ECC?

Comment: They are standard desktop memory non-ECC.

Comment: Perhaps this clarifies what is and isn't supported: https://support.lenovo.com/us/en/solutions/pd027321 For instance, it supports a maximum of 32GB RAM but that doesn't mean it supports 32GB DIMMs or even 2*16GB. In fact, it supports at most an 8GB DIMM per slot so the only way to achieve the 32GB maximum is by using a 4*8GB configuration.